# General use for Semaphores In Java

Tags: java

This program will generate n-LIZARD threads and 1 CAT thread.
Upon “waking up” the LIZARD threads must perform a task “eat”. The lizards must cross from a Sago palm to the Monkey Grass to “eat” and then cross back. The cat thread will wake up after a given time then check to make sure there is no more than 4 LIZARD threads “crossing” at once. The idea is to let the “world” or program run until a given time of 120 seconds has passed and have the lizards protected from the cat.

I know little about the semaphore class and was wondering on how to implement and place a mutuel exclusion, and a regular semaphore. To control the threads in this program using .acquire() and .release().

I know that mutual exclusion will acquire one thread only ( so I was thinking this can be used to control the cat thread (let me know if im wrong)

So my regular semaphore must protect the "crossways".

I have the idea down i just need some help with placement. I commented everything out so you all can be clear on what im trying (failing) to do :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 */
public class LizardsSync 
{
    /*
     * Set this to the number of seconds you want the lizard world to
     * be simulated.  
     * Try 30 for development and 120 for more thorough testing.
     */
    private static int WORLDEND = 120;

    /*
     * Number of lizard threads to create
     */
    private static int NUM_LIZARDS =20;

    /*  
     * Maximum lizards crossing at once before alerting cats
     */
    private static int MAX_LIZARD_CROSSING = 4;

    /*
     * Maximum seconds for a lizard to sleep
     */
    private static int MAX_LIZARD_SLEEP_TIME = 3;

    /*
     * Maximum seconds for a lizard to eat
     */
    private static int MAX_LIZARD_EAT_TIME = 5;

    /*
     * Number of seconds it takes to cross the driveway
     */
    private static int CROSS_TIME = 2;

    /*
     * Number of seconds for the cat to sleep.
     */
    private static int MAX_CAT_SLEEP;

    /*
     * A counter that counts the number of lizzards crossing sago to monkey grass
     */
    int numCrossingSago2MonkeyGrass = 0;

    /*
     * A counter that counts the number of lizzards crossing monkey grass to sago
     */
    int numCrossingMonkeyGrass2Sago = 0;

    /**
     * A semaphore to protect the crossway. 

    */
    Semaphore semaphoreCrossway = new Semaphore(MAX_LIZARD_CROSSING);

    /**
     * A semaphore for mutual exclusion.
     */
    Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

    // on both semaphores, you can call acquire() or release()
    /*
     * Indicates if the world is still running.
     */
    private static boolean running = true;

    /*
     * Indicates if you want to see debug information or not.
     */
    private static boolean debug = true;


    public void go()
    {
        ArrayList<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

        // create all the lizzard threads
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_LIZARDS; i++) 
        {       allThreads.add(new LizardThread(i) );
            allThreads.get(i).start();
}
        // create the cat thread
        Thread CatThread = new CatThread();
         CatThread.start();

        // let the world run for a while
        sleep (WORLDEND);

        // terminate all threads
        running = false;
        // wait until all threads terminate by joining all of them
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_LIZARDS; i++) {
            try {
               allThreads.get(i).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println ("unable to join thread, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
       /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // starts the program
        new LizardsSync().go();
    }

     /**
     * Models a cat thread.
     */
    public class CatThread extends Thread {


        /**
         * @see java.lang.Runnable.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {   
            while (running) {


                   // sleep for a while
                   catSleep();
                   // check on lizzards

                   checkCrossway();

            }
        }

        /**
         * Puts cat thread to sleep for a random time.
         */
        public void catSleep()
        {
            int sleepSeconds  = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*MAX_CAT_SLEEP);

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Cat is sleeping for " + sleepSeconds + " seconds.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
            try {
                sleep(sleepSeconds*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Cat awakes.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Simulates cat checking the crossway.
         */
        public void checkCrossway()
        {

            if (numCrossingMonkeyGrass2Sago + numCrossingSago2MonkeyGrass > MAX_LIZARD_CROSSING) {
                System.out.println ("The cat says yum!");
                System.out.flush();
                     System.exit(-1);
            }
       }
    }

    /**
     * Models a lizard thread.
     */
    public class LizardThread extends Thread {

        private int _id;

        /**
         * Creates a new lizard thread.
         * 
         * @param id the id assigned to the lizard thread
         */
        public LizardThread(int id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }

        /**
         * @see java.lang.Runnable.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {    

            while (running) {
               // sleep for a while in sago
               lizardSleep();
               // wait until safe to cross from sago to monkey grass
               sagoToMonkeyIsSafe();
               // cross path to monkey grass
               crossedOverToMonkey();
               // eat in the monkey grass
               lizardEat();
               // wait untill its safe to cross back to sago
               monkeyToSagoIsSafe();
               // cross from cross monkey grass to sage
               crossMonkeyToSago();
            }
        }

        /**
         * This tests if it is safe to travel from sago to monkey.
         * 
         */
        public void sagoToMonkeyIsSafe() 
        {

                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] checks sago -> monkey grass.");
                    System.out.flush();
                }



                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] thinks sago -> monkey grass is safe.");
                    System.out.flush();
                }


        }

        /**
         * Indicates that lizard crossed over to monkey grass.
         */
        public void crossedOverToMonkey()
        {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] made it to monkey grass.");
                System.out.flush();
            }

           if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] thinks monkey grass -> sago is safe.");
                System.out.flush();

            }
        }


        /**
         * This tests if it is safe to travel from monkey to sago.
         */
        public void monkeyToSagoIsSafe() 
        {

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] checks monkey grass -> sago.");
                System.out.flush();
            }



            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] thinks monkey grass -> sago is safe.");
                System.out.flush();

            }
        }

        /**
         * Indicates that lizard crossed over to sago.
         */
        public void crossedOverToSago()
        {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] made it to sago.");
                System.out.flush();
            }

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] thinks sago -> monkey grass is safe.");
                System.out.flush();
        }
        }
        /**
         * Indicates that lizard is crossing over from monkey to sago.
         */
        void crossMonkeyToSago()
        {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] is crossing monkey grass to sago.");
                System.out.flush();
            }

            numCrossingMonkeyGrass2Sago++;

            // simulate walk
            try {
                sleep(CROSS_TIME*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            numCrossingMonkeyGrass2Sago--;
        }

        /**
         * Indicates that lizard is crossing over from sago to monkey. 
         */
        void crossSagoToMonkey()
        {

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] is crossing sago to monkey grass.");
                System.out.flush();
            }

            numCrossingSago2MonkeyGrass++;

            // simulate walk
            try {
                sleep(CROSS_TIME*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            numCrossingSago2MonkeyGrass--;
        }


        /**
         * Puts lizard thread to sleep for a random amount of time.
         */
        public void lizardSleep()
        {
            int sleepSeconds  = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*MAX_LIZARD_SLEEP_TIME);

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] is sleeping for " + sleepSeconds + " seconds.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
            try {
                sleep(sleepSeconds*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] awakes.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Simulates lizard eating for a random amount of time.
         */
        public void lizardEat()
        {
            int eatSeconds  = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*MAX_LIZARD_EAT_TIME);

            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] is eating for " + eatSeconds + " seconds.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
            try {
                sleep(eatSeconds*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println ("Lizard [" + _id + "] finished eating.");
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Puts current thread to sleep for a specified amount of time.
     * 
     * @param seconds the number of seconds to put the thread to sleep
     */
    private static void sleep(int seconds)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LizardsSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have to cross path you will call `acquire` and whenever you have crossed path you can call `release`

```
Semaphore semaphore= new Semaphore(No of Lizards that can cross the road at a time);


sagoToMonkeyIsSafe();<-- semaphore.acquire(); as crossing the path start
 // cross path to monkey grass
crossedOverToMonkey();<---semaphore.release(); as crossing the path end

monkeyToSagoIsSafe();<-- semaphore.acquire(); as crossing the path start
// cross from cross monkey grass to sage
crossMonkeyToSago();<---semaphore.release();  as crossing the path end
```

Comment: Yep thats what i thought. Im guessing i could use mutex as a fail safe for the cat thread to keep it checking once and only once.

Comment: @wat if you want to let one cross at a time then use semaphore with counter 1 if you want more to cross then increase the semaphore count

Comment: @wat  But then your cat will always be hungry ;)

Comment: Exactly at ts point im not going with mutual exclusion. So I believe that was my issue.

Comment: Thats the idea. Its simply  a "check up" thread. This program is made to demonstrate what happens when with multithreading when one conflicts with another.

Comment: One more question. Is it better to "try catch "or throw in this case. Because there will be a case in which the threads want to "run wild"

Comment: I think it is better to throw exception and handle it in your thread. But then you will need to decide interruption policy whether you want to close application when one thread throws exception or you want to continue ignoring that.

Comment: @wat I will be available again in the evening I will ping you then :-)

Comment: @wat I read your question it is not deadlock your cat thread is running forever so it is supposed to happen. I was about to answer and you deleted it :)

Comment: yep its a loop issue not a dead lock issue so I deleted it.